# can i update my podspec while keeping the same spec version

Tags: ios, cocoapods

i have a podspec that is pushed to the trunk. Now, i need to make few changes to my podspec and push it again. However, i do not wish to change the version number. can i update my podspec and push it to the trunk keeping the version number same?

for.e.g.,

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "MySDKName"
  s.version      = "1.1.0"
  s.summary      = "Pod Summary"
  s.author       = { "Deepak Badiger" => "email@domain.com" }
  s.homepage     = "www.myhomepage.com"
  s.license      = {My License Agreement}
  s.source       = { My Source }
  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
end
```

in the example above, i wish to add -

```
s.subspec 'Categories' do |c|
  c.source_files = 'cats/Classes/*.{h,m}'
end
```

however, i wish to keep the version as 1.1.0 and i don't want to bump the version to 1.1.1 or 1.1.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to bump the version. **And this is how you should do it.**

<s>An alternative</s> A bad idea would be to submit a pull request on [Cocoapods/Specs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) but this will take time and [annoy people](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/pull/12199).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for the suggestions. I knew we don't have open options, however i wanted an expert opinion on the topic. Thanks.